# Simplifying multiple jQuery Dialog function

Tags: javascript, jquery, dialog

As I searched through Stackoverflow and Google, I couldn't find a solution to simplifying my code (or maybe I haven't found the exact search term). It really bugs me that I couldn't simplify the code below.

Since I'm a beginner in this field, I had to repeat all the same code all over again, when there are similarities that I can combine.

Your help is much appreciated!

```
$('.detail-view').dialog({
  autoOpen: false,
  draggable: false,
  resizable: false,
  closeOnEscape: true,
  modal: true,
  height: 'auto',
  width: 600,
  position: ['top', 150] });

$('.forgotpass').dialog({
  autoOpen: false,
  draggable: false,
  resizable: false,
  closeOnEscape: true,
  modal: true,
  height: 'auto',
  width: 400,
  position: ['top', 150] });

$('.user0').load('php/usersetting.php').dialog({
  autoOpen: true,
  draggable: false,
  resizable: false,
  closeOnEscape: false,
  modal: true,
  height: 'auto',
  width: 500,
  position: ['top', 150],
  open: function(){
    $(this).parent().find('.ui-dialog-titlebar-close').hide();
  } });

$('.user1').load('php/usersetting.php').dialog({
  autoOpen: false,
  draggable: false,
  resizable: false,
  modal: true,
  height: 'auto',
  width: 500,
  position: ['top', 100] });

$('.user2').load('php/usersetting.php').dialog({
  autoOpen: true,
  draggable: false,
  resizable: false,
  closeOnEscape: true,
  modal: true,
  height: 'auto',
  width: 500,
  position: ['top', 150],
  open: function(){
    $(this).parent().find('.ui-dialog-titlebar-close').hide();
  }
  });
```

Comment: Start with a basic object and then use `$.extend()` to make variations. Also, take advantage of the `,` in selector syntax to combine separate calls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the vast majority of your options are the same, a simple answer is to create a default options object:

```
var defaults = {
  autoOpen: false,
  draggable: false,
  resizable: false,
  closeOnEscape: true,
  modal: true,
  height: 'auto',
  width: 200,
  position: ['top', 150]
};
```

and then use [`$.extend`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/) with the specific options you want to override:

```
$('.detail-view').dialog($.extend({}, defaults, {
  width: 600
}));
$('.forgotpass').dialog($.extend({}, defaults, {
  width: 400
}));
```

You could encapsulate this in a function:

```
function createDialog(selector, options) {
    $(selector).dialog($.extend({}, defaults, options));
}

createDialog('.detail-view', {
  width: 600
});
createDialog('.forgotpass', {
  width: 400
});
```

Or of course if it's *just* `width`:

```
function createDialog(selector, width) {
    $(selector).dialog($.extend({}, defaults, {width: width}));
}

createDialog('.detail-view', 600);
createDialog('.forgotpass', 400);
```

Comment: Even without trying the code, I can understand its simplicity. You're fast and I'm gonna try it now! Thanks! I'll return shortly.

Comment: Done and works! Thanks a lot for introducing me to `$.extend` !

Answer (score 0):

Create an object and then pass it to each dialog() function:
`var dialog_properties = {autoOpen:false, drag able: false, ...};`

Then use it in all dialog() functions that are similar :

`$('.detailView').dialog(dialog_properties);
$('.forgotPass').dialog(dialog_properties);
...`